# Find the max/min value of an Associative Array made up of numbers

Tags: arrays, bash, comparison, associative-array

GOAL: Find the max/largest value of an associative array that is composed of integer values.

```
  max_val=${RA[0]}
        for i in "${RA[@]}"
        do
                #let count=count+1
                #curr_val=$i
                (( $i > max_val )) && max_val=$i
        done

echo "CURR.MAX: $max_val"
```

ISSUE: When running the previously mentioned code I'm not getting a valid result. I'm also noticing that the `max_val` variable that is being used for comparison seems to have no value. Additionally, I would like to obtain the minimum of the array--which I imagine would be obtained in a similar manner.

Comment: The problem is probably with how you define that array. Many times, one doesn't build it correctly and get a string instead. Show us how `RA` is built.

Comment: The RA array is declared as an associative array, here is what I believe to be relevant code.  ```declare -A RA``` --the declaration of the array. Also here is some additional code ```while read labl val
do
        let RA[$labl]=$val
        # retain the largest value; for scaling
        (( val > max )) && max=$val
done ```